# Changing Org wide defaults to "Public Read/Write' for Contact - Any consideration?

Tags: access

As an organization we decided to make the Org wide default acccess for Contacts from 'Public Read Only' to 'Public Read/Write'.

Before I do the change, do I need to perform any activities ?.  Any best practices ?

Comment: I don't know about systematically. But, you will probably want to do some form of training with your users. Depending on the size of your user base, that could be a sit-down in a room with a tv or projector showing what the change will look like (shouldn't take more than a few minutes total) or it could be an email with some screenshots showing the before and after screens with some rules and warnings in place. The reason is that changing that from read only to read/write will add the edit button to the screen, and some people like to randomly push new buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would ensure that at no point you will want to secure some contacts from a group of people. In Salesforce, you can always give open access to records but you cannot restrict it further than what the OWD says.

If you think you will need to secure a group of contacts from the "General Population" (maybe some secret customer, or similar) then an alternative would be to explore Sharing Rules.

If you're 100% sure that you don't want to secure some contacts, just go for it. You can always change your mind later.

Comment: Technical front, I just need to goto Sharing settings and making the value from 'Public Read only' to 'Public Read/Write' ?. Any other changes required ?

Comment: Nope, that's it!